# How to label the group with larger point numbers as ‘0’ in sklearn k-means clustering

Tags: python, scikit-learn

When using K-means clustering method in sklearn, I clustered the points into two groups. How to  set k_means.labels_ of the group with larger point numbers
as ‘0’ (instead of 1)?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain a bit what your ultimate goal is? I cannot think of a situation where I would want to do that.

Comment: @cel Because I want to compare the true label value with the clustering result and my true labels with 0 value is more than with 1 value. But the clustering randomly labeled my group as 0 and 1, so I want to labeled the group with larger numbers as '0'

Comment: can't you just calculate a confusion matrix between your k-means labels and your true labels?

Comment: @aplassard If you don't change the k-means, the confusion matrix's columns will be switched, and I can't tell if it is switched or not. Also I need to plot the points in the right way.

Comment: Just calculate the confusion matrix manually

Answer (score 2):

Generally, if you have fully labeled data, you should be using a classifier (see [this excellent graphic](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/machine_learning_map/index.html)). K-means is a partially random process, so there is no way to guarantee which cluster is assigned to which label.

Once you have the predictions, if you want to reverse the class labels, you can do something like this:

```
predictions = k_means.fit_predict( my_data )
if sum( predicitons==1 ) > sum( predictions==0 ):
    corrected_predictions = predictions.copy()
    corrected_predictions[ predictions==1 ] = 0
    corrected_predictions[ predictions==0 ] = 1
```

Mucking about with the automatically computed members of a class (like `k_means.labels_`) is **not recommmended.**